# put buttons on the right in ionic so it looks like this picture

Tags: css, ionic-framework

What should be done to put buttons as well as in the picture? (one on the left and 2 right) within the header of my application.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this code should create a header bar with title and one left button and 2 on the right:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">      
    <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-positive">
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="button">Left Button</button>
        </div>
        <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
        <div class="buttons">
             <button class="button">Right Button 1</button>
             <button class="button">Right Button 2</button>
        </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
</ion-header-bar>
```

**for a list:**

```
<ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-button-right">              
        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="button button-positive">
                Button 1
            </button>
            <button class="button button-assertive">
                Button 2
            </button>
          </div>
      </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: thanks for answering, and in case I have a list, how I can do the same effect to have a button on the left and 2 right? http://i.imgur.com/TPWkTIm.png

Comment: plz check my updated answer, in the future plz create another question for a list item in ionic, as the one you did asking for a header not list or edit your question so it will be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You must work with `<ion-nav-buttons side = "left/right">`

Try this

```
<ion-view>

<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>

<ion-nav-title>
    <img class="cabecalho" src="img/????.png">
</ion-nav-title>

<ion-nav-buttons side="right">      
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-ios-list" ng-click="sairAplicativo()"></button>
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-power" ng-click="sairAplicativo()"></button>     
</ion-nav-buttons>

<ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
      ....
</ion-content>
```

I hope that I have helped in some way